# Decrease vertices in curved plane

Tags: modeling, vertices

I want to make a road for an assetto corsa road but there are too many vertices, and I don't know how to reduce them but have the same "smoothness". How to reduce the amount of vertices?

[image]

Comment: Use the X > Limited Dissolve tool, and tweak the Max Angle value in the Operator Box? To keep the shape smooth, give it a Subdivision Surface?

Comment: "How do I make the letters bigger but use less ink?" I can't be sure based on limited info provided, but I'm afraid there might be no answer: reducing the number of vertices will likely reduce smoothness if there are no redundant vertices present…

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Make the arrayed plane much longer (As long as it is wide) and give it a subdivision modifier instead of having a lot of sections in the array. This should be less intensive

If you use a decimate modifier on this it should still respect the curvature
[image]

The curve you are using has a very sharp turn on the top. Roads are usually a lot softer even on tight turns. You should probably not make it as pronounced

Comment: Hmm it don't work as intended i think https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdAxn.jpg

Comment: Put the subdivision before the curve modifier. Otherwise it will smooth it too much